# await never resolve and the next line after that never executed

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, promise, async-await

I am using async await and my await never resolve so the next line does not executed at all. By that I mean this line:

```
result = await IndexingStatusResult(req, res);
```

in the following code:

```
router.post(
  "/api/result-store/v1/indexing-analyzer/:searchID/:id",
  async (req, res) => {
    console.log("Indexing started");
    var hrstart = process.hrtime();
    let result = null;

    result = await IndexingStatusResult(req, res);
    console.log("result is: ", result.data);
    hrend = process.hrtime(hrstart);
    console.info("Execution time (hr): %ds %dms", hrend[0], hrend[1] / 1000000);

    res.status(200).send({
      indexingTimeSec: hrend[0],
      indexingTimeMillSec: hrend[1] / 1000000
    });
  }
);
```

But as you see in IndexingStatusResult I return a promise when everything is done:

```
const IndexingStatusResult = async (req, res) => {
  const docID = parseInt(req.params.id) * 1000;
  const dbName = "test_" + req.params.searchID;
  let result = null;
  try {
    result = await axios(
      `${params.HOST_NAME_WITH_PROTOCOL}/${dbName}/_design/searchAll/_search_info/searchAll`
    );
    result = result.data;
    console.log(
      "Number of docs indexed:",
      result.search_index.doc_count,
      "Total Docs needs to be indexed:",
      docID
    );
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
  console.log(`result returned is : ${JSON.stringify(result)}`);
  if (!result || parseInt(result.search_index.doc_count) < docID) {
return Promise.resolve(
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("WWWWWAAAAIIIIIITING");
    IndexingStatusResult(req, res);
  }, 5000)
);
  } else {
    console.log("YAAAAAAYYYYYYYYYYYYY");
    return Promise.resolve(result);
  }
};
```

Here is what I see:

```
Example app listening on port 3005!
Indexing started
Number of docs indexed: 0 Total Docs needs to be indexed: 5000
result returned is : {"name":"_design/searchAll/searchAll","search_index":{"pending_seq":0,"doc_del_count":0,"doc_count":0,"disk_size":0,"committed_seq":0}}
result is:  undefined
Execution time (hr): 0s 314.964402ms
WWWWWAAAAIIIIIITING
Number of docs indexed: 0 Total Docs needs to be indexed: 5000
result returned is : {"name":"_design/searchAll/searchAll","search_index":{"pending_seq":0,"doc_del_count":0,"doc_count":0,"disk_size":0,"committed_seq":0}}
WWWWWAAAAIIIIIITING
Number of docs indexed: 5001 Total Docs needs to be indexed: 5000
result returned is : {"name":"_design/searchAll/searchAll","search_index":{"pending_seq":5001,"doc_del_count":0,"doc_count":5001,"disk_size":797698,"committed_seq":0}}
YAAAAAAYYYYYYYYYYYYY
```

So the following line never gets executed:

```
console.log("result is: ", result.data);
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Is this the full log? I think `"result is: "` should fire at least once (with `result` being `undefined`). There should also be an unhandled promise exception error too in that case (accessing `result.data` should throw).

Comment: @Joseph Thanks Joseph yes you are right I get that and then the logs above. I did not put the full log. Logs updated please look at it :)

Comment: It should be noted that if your `if` condition is met, nothing is returned -- you should probably wrap that `setTimeout` in a promise and return it (resolving it with the result of your recursive call to `IndexingStatusResult`).

Comment: @HereticMonkey thanks for the input but even before that I am very curious to know why I see this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined because await should not resolve until IndexingStatusResult is done

Comment: If it goes into your `if` condition it will never resolve, and will return `undefined` instead of a promise.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Updated based on your suggestion the error is gone but still the await does not wait properly. Please check the updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues:

- You write *"But as you see in `IndexingStatusResult` I return a promise when everything is done"*. This statement shows a misconception: An `async` function returns a promise *synchronously*, not when "everything" (asynchronous) is done.
- *"My await never resolve[s]"*: It does, and sooner than you think. The statement `console.log("result is: ", result.date)` *does* get executed, but it is the one that triggers the error.
- The call of `setTimeout` in `IndexingStatusResult` does not delay the resolution moment of the promise that it returns. As you do nothing more after the call to `setTimeout` (in an edit, you *return* explicitly here), the promise fulfils with `undefined`.
  At this stage the `setTimeout` callback has not yet executed. The `undefined` resolution value explains the error you get.
- It should also be noted that you already had `result = result.data`, so even if you would have returned that as resolution value, `result.data` would not exist.
- Instead of the `setTimeout` call, do `await delay(5000)`, where `delay` returns a promise that resolves after a timeout.
- In an `async` function you don't need to wrap the return value as a promise. As stated above, the promise object was already returned, and the actual `return` statement should indicate the *value* with which that promise should now resolve.

So (without testing), I would say this code would do the job better:

```
router.post(
  "/api/result-store/v1/indexing-analyzer/:searchID/:id",
  async (req, res) => {
    console.log("Indexing started");
    var hrstart = process.hrtime();
    let result = null;

    result = await IndexingStatusResult(req, res);
    console.log("result is: ", result); // not .data
    hrend = process.hrtime(hrstart);
    console.info("Execution time (hr): %ds %dms", hrend[0], hrend[1] / 1000000);

    res.status(200).send({
      indexingTimeSec: hrend[0],
      indexingTimeMillSec: hrend[1] / 1000000
    });
  }
);

// Helper function that's very useful in async functions:
const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

const IndexingStatusResult = async (req, res) => {
  const docID = parseInt(req.params.id) * 1000;
  const dbName = "test_" + req.params.searchID;
  let result = null;
  while (true) {
    try {
      result = await axios(
        `${params.HOST_NAME_WITH_PROTOCOL}/${dbName}/_design/searchAll/_search_info/searchAll`
      );
      result = result.data;
      console.log(
         "Number of docs indexed:",
        result.search_index.doc_count,
        "Total Docs needs to be indexed:",
        docID
      );
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      return e; // ?? determine what you want to happen...
    } 
    console.log(`result returned is : ${JSON.stringify(result)}`);
    if (result && parseInt(result.search_index.doc_count) >= docID) break;
    await delay(5000); // delay and keep looping
  }
  console.log("YAAAAAAYYYYYYYYYYYYY");
  return result;
};
```